# STL allocators and operator new[]

Tags: c++, stl, allocator, new-operator

Are there STL implementations that use `operator new[]` as an allocator? On my compiler, making `Foo::operator new[]` private did not prevent me from creating a `vector<Foo>`... is that behavior guaranteed by anything?

Answer (score 4):

C++ Standard, section 20.4.1.1.  The default allocator allocate() function uses global operator new:

```
pointer allocate(size_type n, allocator<void>::const_pointerhint=0);

3 Notes: Uses ::operator new(size_t) (18.4.1).
```

Comment: Can't find such statement in C++ Standard. Which revision do you use?

Comment: It's 20.4.1.1, not 24.4.1.1, which might explain why Kirill didn't find it.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `::operator new[]` instead of `::operator new` to allocate blocks of memory intended to hold a sequence of objects instead of a single object?

Comment: I'm just quoting from the standard. For discussions of WHY the standard does things, I suggest asking in the usenet group comp.std.c++

Answer (score 2):

std library implementations won't use T::operator new[] for std::allocator. Most of them use their own memory pooling infrastructure behind the scenes.

In general, if you want to stop `Foo` objects being dynamically allocated, you'll have to have make all the constructors private and provide a function that creates `Foo` objects. Of course, you won't be able to create them as `auto` variables either though.

Comment: A vector basically allocates uninitialized memory and places objects therein later as they are added. Reserving memory does not create instances.

Answer (score 2):

std::vector uses an Allocator that's passed as a template argument, which defaults to std::allocate. The allocator doesn't work like `new[]` though -- it just allocates raw memory, and placement `new` is used to actually create the objects in that memory when you tell it to add the objects (e.g. with `push_back()` or `resize()`).

About the only way you could use `new[]` in an allocator would be if you abused things a bit, and allocated raw space using something like `new char[size];`. As abuses go, that one's fairly harmless, but it's still unrelated to your overload of `new[]` for the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prohibit the creation of your object make private constructor rather than `operator new`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers here, if you want to prevent anyone from creating a STL container for your type `Foo`, then simply make the copy-constructor for `Foo` private (also the move-constructor if you're working with C++11).  All STL-container objects must have a valid copy or move constructor for the container's allocator to properly call placement `new` and construct a copy of the object in the allocated memory block for the container.